# android firebase error expected a List while deserializing

Tags: android, json, firebase, arraylist, hashmap

I have seen similar questions, but most of them tries to use HashMap instead 
of List and gets this error.

Error while retrieving data from firebase:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Here is onDataChange:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot a : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                mProducts.add(a.getValue(ProductTest.class));
            }
        }
```

And my ProductTest class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties


public class ProductTest {

private long id;

@SerializedName("remote_id")
private long remoteId;
private long category;
private String code;
private String description;

@SerializedName("main_image")
private String mainImage;

@SerializedName("main_image_high_res")
private String mainImageHighRes;

private List<ProductVariantTest> variants;
private List<ProductTest> related;


public ProductTest() {
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties


public class ProductTest implements Serializable {

private long id;

@SerializedName("remote_id")
private long remoteId;
private long category;
private String code;
private String description;

@SerializedName("main_image")
private String mainImage;

@SerializedName("main_image_high_res")
private String mainImageHighRes;

private List<ProductVariantTest> variants;
private List<ProductTest> related;


public ProductTest() {
}

}


Try this one...
```